# What are the options for sharing sessions between applications?

Tags: session, authentication, single-sign-on

Say that I have two or more completely separate web applications. The might even be running on a different server and use different language & framework.

What I need to do is to share state, or at least authentication. For example if the user logs in on one of the websites and goes to another one, he will be able to authenticate using his credentials from the first website.

For example, if I have one website running e-commerce and another one is a blog, I want all the e-commerce users be able to comment on the blog with the information from their profile.

What is the best way to do this? Is it even a good idea?

The only solution that comes to my mind is abstracting away the profiles and authentication and create some kind of *global profile* and then use that on both of those websites. But that seems like a really complex solution considering what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenID](http://openid.net/) seems like a good way.